# Attempted import error: 'DatePicker' is not exported from 'gestalt'

Tags: reactjs

I want to use DatePicker in gestalt but getting errors like the title.
Everything else provided gestalt such as TextField, Box, FieldSet...  is fine.
I followed the instructions written down here:

https://gestalt.netlify.app/DatePicker

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import Header from "../component/Header";
import Footer from "../component/Footer";

import { DatePicker } from "gestalt";
import "gestalt/dist/gestalt.css";

const Example = (props) => {
  const handleChange = (value) => value;
  return (
    <div>
      <DatePicker
        id="example-basic"
        label="Select a date"
        onChange={({ value }) => handleChange(value)}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

class Post extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header />
        <Box padding={10}>
          <Example></Example>
        </Box>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Post;
```

And my terminal says:

[image: preview]

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import DatePicker from 'gestalt-datepicker';
```

The documentation show import statement like this.